# Scala can't find method even after import

Tags: scala, import

I have been given a test in Scala:

```
import java.nio.file._
import PathImplicits._
import java.io._

test("Paths should have a .write method to create files") {
    val p = Paths.get("test.txt")
    val contents = "This should write a file"
    try {
        p.write(contents)
        assert(new String(Files.readAllBytes(p)) == contents)
    }
    finally {
        Files.deleteIfExists(p)
    }
}
```

However when I run it, I get an error:

```
value write is not a member of java.nio.file.Path
[error]       p.write(contents)
```

Which import am I missing? I thought that `java.nio.file._` would cover that.

Comment: Not sure what you're intending, but `Path` does not have a `.write` method: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html You probably meant `Files.write(p, contents, options)` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html

Comment: What is PathImplicits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no write method for both Path and Paths classes. I think you are looking for [`java.nio.file.Files.write`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-byte:A-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-) method. Here is how to fix your code:

```
test("Paths should have a .write method to create files") {
    val p = Paths.get("test.txt")
    val contents = "This should write a file"
    try {
        Files.write(p, contents.getBytes) // consider using a charset here
        assert(new String(Files.readAllBytes(p)) == contents)
    }
    finally {
        Files.deleteIfExists(p)
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, now I get an error that says that object path is not a member of package <root>

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if you are missing an import, this error says that the compiler can't find a method name `write` on the class `Path` like other people mentioned. However there is one way this could be an issue with imports, you could be missing an import to an implicit conversion. In that case the imported code should look something like this

```
implicit class PathImplicits(val p: Path) {
    def write(x: Any) = ???
}
```